# Python Writing Strings Inconsistently to File

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I am writing a python code that will write input files for another program. I have a test suite, and I have been finding that the tests will sometimes fail because strings that are written may be missing characters or use "e" instead of "E" for the notation of a floating point number. But these failures seem to happen randomly.

I have no idea how to approach this problem, I've googled around and can't seem to find any results that match my problem.

Here is the results from two runs of unit test with no code changes between them:

```
..................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 82 tests in 0.019s

OK
```

Then the Failures in the form of diff output(spaces replaced with `):

```
<  Begin feti equation solver feti
<  End feti equation solver feti
---
>   Begin feti equation_solver feti
>   End feti equation_solver feti
```

and

```
<   tolerance = 1E-06
---
>   tolerance = 1e-06
```

Here is an the write method that writes these passages:

```py
  def write(self,f,indent):
    # if this term  is not active do not write anything
    if not self._active:
      return()
    line = "  " * indent
    for idx,item in enumerate(self._my_values):
      if item is None:
        continue
      if idx != 0:
        line+=" "
      if self._use_symbol and idx == self._symbol_location:
        line += self._symbol+" "
      line += str(item)
    line += "\n"
    f.write(line)
```

_my_values is a list of strings, ints or floats. 
_symbol is a string, often an "=".

I'd like it such that the tests would behave consistently. While the "e" vs "E" is not a big deal, the change in underscores really is.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks like the problem might be in the contents of `self._my_values` - perhaps you should be looking at how they are generated?

Comment: Thanks Looking closer at it I found some inconsistencies with my 'gold' strings. But now that brings in to question my unittest is only showing these errors sometimes.

Comment: Maybe `self._symbol` and `self._symbol_location` could be getting out of sync?